# Why SPWeb.Group provide a method named Add() that always raises exceptions (that we can not use)

Tags: 2013, development, groups, spweb, console-application

I have the following inside my c# console application

```
 using (SPSite site = new SPSite(scurl))  //site collection url
 {
       using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb(subsiteurl0)) //specific subsite url
       {//code goes here
            subSite.Groups.Add(currentgroupname, site.RootWeb.SiteAdministrators[0], site.RootWeb.SiteAdministrators[0], "desc");
       }
 }
```

Now, I was surprised that the `SPWeb.Groups` property has a method named `Add()`.. so I tried to test it using the above code but i got this exception :-

```
You cannot add a group directly to the Groups collection.  You can add a group to the SiteGroups collection.
```

Now, I know that I can fix this by replacing `subsite.Groups.Add()` with `subsite.siteGroups.Add()` and it will work well.

But my question is why does SharePoint provide `SPWeb.Groups.Add()` method that we can not use? or there are scenarios that we can add a group from the `SPWb.Groups`. Now, I tried this on a `SPWeb` that have unique permission and on another which inherit its permissions but both raise the same exception as described above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer to this question is, `Add` method is there for Type consistency which makes the life easier for the Developers, both the SharePoint library(dll) developers and general SharePoint Developers(dll integrators).

Since the `Type` of `SPWeb.Groups` property is `Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGroupCollection`, it has to have the `Add` method.

Now, one could argue that another `Type` could have been created for `SPWeb.Groups` property but that would have:

First> added a lot of repeated code to the SharePoint library codebase and decreased the potential maintainability,

Second> enlarged the learning curve for general SharePoint Developers as now they need to remember two different Types and their members.

Answer (score 2):

Let me first elaborate the difference between **SPWeb.Groups** and **SPWeb.SiteGroups**

- **SPWeb.Groups** Get a collection that contains all the groups for the subsite.
- **SPWeb.SiteGroups** Get a collection that contains all the groups in the site collection.

**Regarding the error:**

- You got this error because group permissions are located in site collections, not subsites.

**Regarding why Microsoft added `Add()` function to `Groups`?**

The `Groups` in this syntax is considered as a `GroupCollection` that already has `Add()` function to add a group to the collection of groups in a **site collection** not a subsite. Meanwhile, you can't use it with this way `Groups.Add()` where you will get your above error. and to overcome this issue you should use `AssociatedGroups.Add` as mentioned in the next point.

**Regarding How to add a Group to Subsite Programmatically**

You should first add the group to site collection level as you have mentioned, then use `AssociatedGroups.Add` ,

Try the following code.

```
private static void AddGroup(SPWeb web, SPRoleType roleType, string groupName)
    {
        var groups = web.SiteGroups;

        var userGroup = FindSiteGroup(web.Site, groupName);

        if (userGroup == null)
        {
            groups.Add(groupName, web.CurrentUser, null, string.Empty);
            web.AssociatedGroups.Add(web.SiteGroups[groupName]);
        }

        var grp = web.SiteGroups[groupName];
        grp.OnlyAllowMembersViewMembership = false;
        grp.Update();

        if (roleType != SPRoleType.None)
        {
            var asgn = new SPRoleAssignment(web.SiteGroups[groupName]);
            var roleDef = web.RoleDefinitions.GetByType(roleType);
            asgn.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add(roleDef);
            web.RoleAssignments.Add(asgn);
        }

        web.Update();
    }
```

Comment: M.Qassas thanks for the repy,, but correct me if i am wrong.. now i do not need to explicitly associate a group to a SPWeb as follow `web.AssociatedGroups.Add(web.SiteGroups[groupName]);` ,, because when you define `web.RoleAssignments.Add(asgn);` this will automatically associate the group to the web ..is this correct?

Comment: Yes @johnG it's correct , AssociatedGroups will make your group added to sub-site in the People and Group page. and once you add role assignment this group will take a permission to your site.

Comment: i do not think this is 100% correct... as when you create a new Group on the rootWeb and you specify not to have any permission, then this new group will be shown inside the "people and Group" for all the subsites but not inside the "site permission" ... so i am not sure if web.AssociateGroup is requrired in this case also.. can u adivce please?

Comment: To make it clear. let's do the following scenario, open your subsite in the browser, go to site settings people and group, add a new group, this group will be added directly the root site collection in people and group page and all subsite people and group page! Meanwhile, it will be added also to the site permission for only this subsite, and for this, you need to use the web.AssociateGroup.Add() to do the same behavior,

Comment: now try to repeat the above steps on root site by creating a new group in people and group in root site, you will note that the group is added to all subsites people and group page but not added to site permission page of your subsite. Hope it's clear now :)

Comment: but my point is that when you use `web.RoleAssignments.Add(asgn); ` this will cause the `groupName` to be automatically get associated to the web.. i mean when you add a role assingment to the web ,, then automatically the related group will be associated to the web...

Comment: i mean .. first you create a `RoleAssignment()` and you pass a `Group`. then you create a `RoleDefinition` and assign it permission level (Read, contribute), then you bind the `RoleDefinition` to the `RoleAssignment`,, finally you associate the `RoleAssignment` to the related `SPWeb()`. so seems these steps will cover Associating a Group to the `SPWeb()`... so no need to explicitly do `web.AssociatedGroups.Add(web.SiteGroups[groupName]);` is this correct?

Comment: Good hint , yes, I got it, no need to use it and if you use it it will not affect the final result of the above code meanwhile I have mentioned to can use it instead of SPWeb.Groups,